# Can I suppress messages that are sent using RAISERROR in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

We currently have an application in ASP.NET and using SQL Server. We have used `RAISERROR`, whenever and wherever required in our stored procedures.

Now the client wants the real `SqlException` to be captured in our try catch, and not the one that is printed in SQL Server.

Is it possible? If yes then can anyone let me know please.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please state a example of what a "real sql exception" would be. also post a code example showing how you are using RAISERROR in your code.

Comment: If an error is caught in a procedure and then redirected with RAISERROR, you cannot get the underlying exception. Post your SQL code as well as your C# code.

Comment: Thanks JimmyV, that answers. Not sure how do I mark it as "answered" now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jimmy for answering that, also I would like to comment on the code.
My SQL stored procedure was like

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE ------------
----------
------
BEGIN TRY
UPDATE table_name
 SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
 WHERE some_column=@some_value
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
RAISEERROR(500001,1,16)
END CATCH
```

So either the rows where not updated, or there was some conversion error, but irrespective of whatever, the user will be displayed only what was described in the RAISEERROR.
I just gave a select @@ERRORMESSAGE after the RAISEERROR and that allowed me to capture details.
So when I got the result back to my application in .NET, along with the RAISEERROR, it also gave me the details of @@ERRORMESSAGE, this helped me out.
Thanks all again.